# Running InstallUtil.exe using different versions of .NET

Tags: .net, wcf

I've got a WCF service running on a Windows 2003 Server, which I wrote using .NET 3.5.  It looks like I'll need to do some modifications to it, and I thought that I'd migrate the service to .NET 4.0 in the process.  I wrote it to use TCP, rather than HTTP, so the WCF service runs another a Windows Service I wrote, too.  To put that service in place on the server, I used the InstallUtil.exe utility.  I've already installed the .NET framework 4.0 on the server, but I'm not sure how to go about uninstalling my Windows Service/WCF service, since there's 2 .NET frameworks there, and presumably each with it's own InstallUtil.exe.  If Visual Studio was installed on the server I could run a command prompt from VS's Tools, but that's not available. So, how do I execute the correct InstallUtil.exe to uninstall the .NET 3.5 version, and then later install the 4.0 version?

Comment: Did you know that you can write a service to be self-installing? Easy enough in 3.5, but in 4.0 there's an extra class **jut for this**. I have mine setup so that if I run it at the console: Works as console; ru it with "-i" and it self-installs (as a service); run it with "-u" and it self-uninstalls; and works fine as a service of course.

Comment: No, I did not know that.  So then, it's no longer necessary for me to write a Windows Service to host a WCF service? What's the name of the class/namespace that does that for you?

Comment: it'll still be a windows service; simply - you don't need any kind of installer or external tools to install it (since installutil is not always available); I'm on mobile at the moment - I can look on Monday if you like, but should be fairly google-able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify the full path on the command-line e.g.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe

Comment: Should use an environment variable instead of c:\windows